# CSS selector not functioning as expected

Tags: html, css

In the following simple document:

```css
div+p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Hi Caitlin! Welcome to CSS!</p>
</div>
```

The text between the 'p' (paragraph) tags is NOT displayed in red despite being the children of the div element. The '~' selector does not function either, but '>' performs as expected. I'm using Chrome 49 on a Windows machine.

Comment: It seems like you need to use '>', as mentioned at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors

Comment: `>` selects children. `~` and `+` select siblings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is the adjacent **sibling** combinator.

The `div` and `p` have a parent/child relationship (`>` is the child combinator while a space is the descendant combinator) not a brother/sister relationship (which would be `<div></div><p></p>`).

Answer (score -1):

`div` is the parent element while `p` is the child element

since the relationship between the elements is parent-child, you have to use `'>'` or `' '`

but note that `div > p` will only select the immediate `p` child elements, it will not work on other `p` elements that are not an immediate child element of the `div`

That is

`.parent > p{ color: red; }`

only works like this

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>this will be in red color</p>
    <div>
        <p>this will NOT be in red color</p>
    </div>
    <p>this will also be in red color</p>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>this will NOT be in red color</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but

`.parent p{ color: red; }`

works like this

```
<div class="parent">
    <p>this will be in red color</p>
    <div>
        <p>this will also be in red color</p>
    </div>
    <p>this will also be in red color</p>
    <div>
        <div>
            <p>this will also be in red color</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```